# Перифраз ли это?

Tags: лексика, стилистика

> В камыше раздавался жалобный крик *водяной курочки*.

Является ли выделенное словосочетание перифразом [камышницы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0), или это просто другое название птицы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В приведенном примере используется другое название предмета, такой прием называется **необразным перифразом.**

Перифраз бывает **образный и обычный**. **Образный перифраз** — это средство художественной выразительности, вид тропа. Перифраз намекает на предмет, называя его существенные свойства (этим он похож на загадку), например: царь зерей — лев, петь дифирамбы — прославлять.

**Обычный перифраз** — это другое наименование предмета, иногда он поясняет смысл, а иногда выполняет стилистическую функцию (позволяет избежать повторов одного слова).

Есть еще **общеязыковые перифразы**: братья наши меньшие, туманный Альбион, они уже не воспринимаются носителями языка как образные.

Answer (score 0):

Считаю, что недостаточно данных для анализа. В расширенном контексте произведения возможно более точно определить принадлежность к научной классификации.

По моему мнению, нет, так как для художественной литературы свойственно применение оборотов речи для красивого словца. На первый взгляд автор специально не уточняет название птицы, а обращает наше внимание на её местообитание и её размеры.

P.S. Это предложение можно найти в романе Алексея Толстого «Князь Серебряный». Автор описывает местность. Поэтому заострять внимание на название птицы не стал.

Comment: Вы говорите, что выражение "обращает наше внимание на ее местообитание и ее размеры", а это как раз значит, что оно является перифразом :) Перифраз — это описательный оборот, который, помимо всего прочего, обладает образностью (согласно узкому пониманию).

Comment: Или, быть может, у вас другое представление о перифразах?

Comment: @Aer солидарен с Вами, при сохранении равнозначного значения. В данном случае: камышница - определённый вид птиц, а "водяная курочка" - в моём представлении, это обитающие на воде птицы.